# Trying to get a large xml file through api.php

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to get the contents of a large xml file from api.My problem is that it takes forever to response actually i waited an hours and still nothing.Even if i try the url to my browser it just time out.Is there a better way to get the file?

Here is my code

```
$fp = fopen('a.xml','wb');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Update:
I used this code but its the same it keeps loading it think its some memory problem it tries to load the whole file before send it to simplexml.If i put RETURNTRANSFER to false it will lower memory usage?

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0", // something like Firefox 
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 0,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
);
$curl = curl_init('someurl.com');
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $options );   
$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I notice immediately with your code snippet is that you open a.xml by assigning the file handle to $fp, but you reference it in your curl_setopt as $fh.

How big is the XML?  Depending on how much memory you allow php to consume, you could get the entire contents of the file with something as simple as:

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents('a.xml');
```

Or if you plan to process the xml further, you could load the file into a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('a.xml');
```

or into a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php):

```
$xmlDom = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDom->load('a.xml');
```

Comment: oups my mistake didnt notice that thanks.The file is about 22mb.After i create the file i will load it to simplexml with that part im ok i tested it with a smaller file from that api but when i try to get all the contents its just stay there forever i have set the time to 0 so it wont time out.i havent tried to get the file with file_get_contents yet i will try it now.

Comment: i tried fle_get_contents and i got an error failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!.